# Visual Studio 2010 Add Service Reference no longer creates binding

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, wcf-binding

Recently, when I try to add a service reference in Visual Studio, it creates an empty binding in the App.config file. It used to create the full binding for me, now it looks like this:

[image]

rather than this

[image]

Any idea why this would be?! Have I accidentally changed a setting somewhere?

Comment: Does the proxy get generated correctly and without any warnings or errors?

Comment: It does get generated correctly. Also, when I add a reference to the same webservice in VS2008 the binding is generated correctly.

Comment: It's been a while since I used 2010 with WCF. Is "Update Service Reference" doing anything to change it after you establish it?

Comment: Hi Joe, nope, updating the service reference doesn't change it unfortunately.

Comment: Is this your issue? It's all I've found so far. :(  http://thomashundley.com/post/2011/12/07/WCF-Service-References-not-generating-webconfig-client-endpoints-and-bindings.aspx